# Number of sides of regular polygon

Tags: geometry, polygons

**What I need to find:** Number of sides of a regular polygon

**What I am given:** Any 3 vertices of the polygon

**What I currently know:** I can find the center of the polygon. That would be the intersection of the perpendicular bisectors of any 2 lines formed by the given points.

**Edit1:** If there are more than one possible values of *n*, I am interested in finding *n* that would result in the minimum area polygon.

Comment: If the given points were consecutive, then something could have been done (calculating the angle between them, and finding $n$). But as it stands,    $n$ can have multiple values

Comment: It is not possible to find exact number of sides with only three vertices; since any regular polygon with $n$ sides, one can create another regular polygon with $2n$ sides without changing the places of vertices. This question will become meaningful if minimum number of sides are asked. If so, then; greatest common divisor (as below answers stated) of three central angles formed by the circle containing three vertices does give number of sides.

Comment: @Tim: I am interested in finding the value of _n_ which would result in the minimum area of the resultant polygon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A, B, C$ be the points on the $n$-sided polygons.

For $\Delta ABC$, denote $a=BC$, etc.

By cosine law, $$A=\cos^{-1} \left( \frac{b^{2}+c^{2}-a^{2}}{2bc} \right)$$

Angle at circumcentre $O$ correspond to arc $BC=2A$, therefore $2A,2B,2C$ should be rational multiples of $2\pi$,

Or equivalently $A=\frac{p\pi}{n},B=\frac{q\pi}{n}, C=\frac{r\pi}{n}$ where $n,p,q,r\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $p+q+r=n$

Thus $$n=
\frac{1}{\gcd \left( \frac{A}{\pi},\frac{B}{\pi},\frac{C}{\pi} \right)}$$

Comment: I didn't understand how you reached the _gcd_ conclusion

Comment: Obviously, if $A, B, C$ are vertices of an equilateral triangle, they also can be the vertices of a regular hexagon for the same circumscribed circle.  All you need is the minimal possible value of $n$.  That's quite natural to choose the $\gcd$.  Check this out with other concrete values: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2Fgcd%5B3%2F4,1%2F6,1%2F12%5D

Comment: But why did you do 1/gcd and not gcd itself?

Comment: If you don't like reciprocal, use $n=\operatorname{lcm} \left( \frac{\pi}{A}, \frac{\pi}{B}, \frac{\pi}{C} \right)$ instead.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$, $B$, $C$ the given points, and $O$ the center, you've constructed. Now if there is a regular polygon, that has the three points as vertices, by Euclidean algorithm you can construct the greatest common divisor of the angles $AOB\angle$, $BOC\angle$, $COA\angle$, name it $\alpha$. 
Still supposed, that there is a regular polygon has the vertices $A$, $B$, $C$, $\frac{2\pi}{\alpha}$ is an integer, name it $n_0$, which is the least number of the vertices of a regular polygon having the vertices $A$, $B$, $C$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that the three given points are vertices of a regular $n$-gon. The angle at $A$ is half the arc subtended by $BC$; therefore $\angle A={ j\over n}\pi$ for some $j\in{\mathbb N}_{\geq1}$. It follows that necessarily all three angles are rational multiples of $\pi$.

Assume, on the other hand, that
$$\angle A={p\over q}\pi,\qquad \angle B={r\over s}\pi$$
in lowest terms. Then 
$${p\over q}={j\over n},\qquad{r\over s}={k\over n}$$
imply that $n$ has to be a multiple of $q$ as well as of $s$, hence $$n=m\ {\rm lcm}(q,s),\qquad m\in{\mathbb N}_{\geq1}\ .\tag{1}$$
On the other hand, any  $n$ of the form $(1)$ gives rise to a regular $n$-gon having the three given points as vertices.